# How to validate date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datepicker

I want to validate date within 2 months between a given date using two(2) datepicker

*example: DATEPICKERdatefrom = 02/05/2013 and DATEPICKERdateto = 03/08/2013 (dd/mm/yyyy)*

**what should be my statement?**

```
if ( /*DATEPICKERdatefrom between DATEPICKERdateto is not between 2 months*/ )
{
messagebox.show("the Date must within 2 months")
}
else
{
//GO
}
```

Comment: Simply a matter of crating new `DateTime` instance of your interest and compare it with `>` and `<` operators.

Comment: Hi, StackOverflow is a site for when you have a problem with existing code. Questions requesting code to be written for you tend to not be well recieved.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how you can offset the date.

```
DateTime twoMonthsBack = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2);
DateTime twoMonthsLater = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
```

you may replace `DateTime.Now` in the example with your date. and you can choose to validate the same.

perhaps

```
if(DATEPICKERdateto > DATEPICKERdatefrom.AddMonths(2))
{
    //to date is more than two months from start date
    messagebox.show("the Date must within 2 months");
}
else
{
    //GO
}
```

above example is based on assumption that from date is always less then to date.

Answer (score 0):

If these values are `DateTime`, you can simply use [`<`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5wecxwa.aspx) or [`>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxk8751b.aspx) operators to compare.

```
if((date > DATEPICKERdatefrom) && (date < DATEPICKERdateto))
```

These operators are overloaded by `DateTime` as;

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool operator < (DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
        return t1.InternalTicks < t2.InternalTicks;
}


[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool operator > (DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
        return t1.InternalTicks > t2.InternalTicks;
}
```